# Where to read Bleach from after the Ichigo & Aizen fight in the anime?

Tags: bleach

I watched the anime up to the Aizen battle and when Ichigo lost his powers. What chapter in the manga should I read from? (I don't want to watch the rest of the anime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually ended up finding this; in chapter 416, the battle with Aizen ends.